# When does $x^{x^{x^{...^x}}}$ diverge but $x^{x^{x^{...^c}}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation, tetration, complex-dynamics

Let us define these two sequences as follows:

$a_0=1$, $b_0=c$

$a_{n+1}=x^{a_n}$, $b_{n+1}=x^{b_n}$

$b_{n+1}\ne b_n$ for any $n$.

$x,c\in\mathbb C$

Is it possible for $a_n$ to diverge but $b_n$ to converge under these conditions?  For example, if $x=2$ and $c=i$, we have

$b_1=2^i=\operatorname{cis}(\ln2)$

$b_2=2^{\operatorname{cis}(\ln2)}=2^{\cos(\ln2)}\operatorname{cis}(\ln2\sin(\ln2))$

etc.

I haven't much clue as to whether it is the case that $b_n$ can converge when $a_n$ diverges, and I can hardly work out if $b_n$ converges with $x=2$ and $c=i$.

Comment: I hope [this](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Knoebelchv.pdf) and [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-05/S0002-9939-1962-0141910-9/S0002-9939-1962-0141910-9.pdf) will help you.

Comment: @Rohan I'm not so sure, both papers cover the topic of my sequence $a_n$, which I already know about, I'm more interested in $b_n$.

Comment: Then the second paper may be useful.

Comment: Hmm, the clause $c \ne x^c$ intends to exclude the "trivial" case of $c$ being the fixpoint. But consider cases , where the exponentialtower to base $x$ has a ***set of cyclic*** fixpoints *(which might also be accumulation points such that the height-increasing exponentialtower of $b_n$ "converges" to a cycle over such a set of points)* then you might want to add an analogue clause/to extend the given clause. (I've not yet a true answer to your question so far)

Comment: hmmm, for real values of x, the first requirement is that x>exp(1/e) so that the first power tower diverges.  But all complex fixed points for bases>exp(1/e) are repelling.  So doesn't that mean the 2nd power tower won't converge?  And therefore there are no real valued solutions to the Op's problem?

Comment: @SheldonL Hm, I'm not entirely sure.  I'm also wondering about $x<e^{-e}$.

Comment: @SimpleArt ouch!, but I think.  $0<b<e^{-e}$ has repelling fixed points.... negative bases?  complex bases? it might be easier to work with iterating $z \mapsto \exp(z)+k;\;\;\;k=\ln(\ln(b))$ which is congruent to $y \mapsto b^y;\;\;\;y=(z-k)/ln(b)$

Comment: @SheldonL Oddly, though I am asking such questions, such vocabulary is new to me.  But it's ok, I get the gist of what you are saying.  If you can think up a worthy answer, go for it and I'll ask clarifications later.  And do complex fixed points behave like real ones?  It seems quite hard to discern

Comment: Even considering complex values of x, I believe the surprising result is that there are no solutions!    I wrote a pari-gp loop that verified this for over 300,000 real and complex bases with attracting fixed points ....  I think this is the case since I think the domain of the basin of attraction of the attracting fixed point can be extended to f'=0; but I will need to do some reading to brush up on complex dynamics, and iterated functions.

Comment: @SheldonL: if you'll get something substantial - I'd like to see a workout also in our tetrationforum! (It seems to be an interesting facet in context with the D. Shell article)

Comment: @SheldonL If you still wish to I would be interested in seeing your numerical results.

Comment: One can work out that the only times that $x^{\ldots^c}$ can converge without hitting a fixed point is whenever $W(-\log(x))$ has absolute value at most $1$, where $W$ is the product log (and there are definitely converging $c$ when this absolute value is *strictly* less than $1$). I would maybe bet that there's an example of this happening where the absolute value is exactly $1$ and that where it's less than $1$, the tower converges starting at $1$.

Comment: @miloBrandt b=exp(1/e) has a neutral fixed point=e, and iterating b^^n converges towards e.